# Grey box appearing on image link with opacity

Tags: html, css

First question on Stack Overflow so if I am missing anything you need just ask and I'll do my best to provide it.

Basically I have a set of images that are acting as links to websites, when you hover over them there is an opacity effect (goes to 0.7). This is fine but when you hover and the opacity kicks in a grey box appears in the middle, I am assuming this is due to it being a link with an anchor tag.

My question is how do I get rid of that grey box? See below for images and code:

HTML for images

```
<div class="col-md-4 centered paddedBottom">
                <p class="uppercase">Angela Macaulay Therapies</p>
                <a href="http://angelamacaulaytherapies.uk" target="_blank">                                
                <img src="images/angelamacaulaytherapies.png" /></a>
</div>
```

This is css for images

```
#our_work img {
width:400px;
height:400px;
display: inline-block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

CSS for hover over images

```
#our_work img:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

IMAGE BEFORE HOVER - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqx8N.png

IMAGE WITH HOVER AND GREY BOX - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNDjD.png

Anything else you need to help let me know!

Comment: Could you provide us with more information? Your problem is not solvable from the code you just gave us. Maybe make an example in JSFiddle?

Comment: Whilst putting together a JSFiddle for you I managed to locate the problem and fix it!

I have a css style that changed the colour of the navbar links on hover but within there it said "a:hover then change colour", so I made it more specific with the ID of the navbar and now it works!

From: 

    .dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a, a:hover {
    background-color:grey !important;
}


To:

    .dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a, #main_nav a:hover {
    background-color:grey !important;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per my comment above in response to Webber, I found the cause of this (for me) was because when changing the colour of the navbar hover effect I was also targeting all anchor tags. This isn't usually noticeable but with the opacity effect this became visible. I changed my code to the following:

From:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a, a:hover {
  background-color:grey !important;
}
```

To:

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a, #main_nav a:hover {
  background-color:grey !important;
}
```